# Getting uninitialized constant error from unused gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, addressable-gem

I was trying to use the [Addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) gem in a specific action in Rails.

My usual practice is to include the gem in the Gemfile, and then require the module where needed.

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'addressable'
```

**some_controller.rb:**

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  def new
    require "addressable/uri"
    current_url = Addressable::URI.parse(request.original_url)
    ....
  end

end
```

However, I was getting a 500 error on other actions/controllers that did not use the gem.

> Error during failsafe response: uninitialized constant Addressable

Finally, I removed *all* the code calling addressable, but kept the entry in the gemfile, and the 500 error persists on all actions. Why would this be?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you're getting that specific error, but with a gem like Addressable where you **don't** want an automatic `require 'addressable'` performed then in your `Gemfile` you should have:

```
gem 'addressable', :require => false
```

Comment: @smathy- no luck! `:require => false` doesn't change anything, still getting the error on everything. And when I tried `:require => true` I get Bundler error: "cannot load such file -- addressable (LoadError)"

Comment: And if you remove the line from your Gemfile then the error goes away?

Comment: NO! I just removed the gem line from the Gemfile, ran `bundle install`, and restarted the server- *STILL* getting errors- wtf!?

Comment: Right, so either you have another "Addressable" somewhere in your code, or your app hasn't restarted properly.

Comment: The only place addressable shows up is as a dependency for the lanuchy gem in my Gemfile.lock, but that's been there for months. Absolutely no idea what's up- giving up on this, I'll just require the module in my initializer, which solves this crap. Thanks for the help..